# How to add Rules "Context variables" based on node fields?

Tags: rules, 9

I am doing a Data comparison in rules condition. But while adding "Context variables -> Data Selectors", I am unable to add node fields like "node.ABC.value" or "node.ABC".
It's throwing errors like Data selector "node.ABC" for context Data to compare is invalid.
Any suggestions?